# NuxtJS & Bootstrap Vue - Best way to change image from Card Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

**Wanted outcome :** create a card component that I can use through several different pages. I want to define directly on each page the top image that I want to use within the component.

**The Card Component** :

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <b-card img-alt="Card image" img-top>
      <b-card-img :src="imageUrl" alt="Image" bottom></b-card-img>
      <b-card-text>
        Some quick example text to build on the card and make up the bulk of the
        card's content.
      </b-card-text>
    </b-card>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    imageUrl: String,
    required: true
  }
};
</script>
```

**The index page** :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Card ></Card>
     </div>
      <
</template>

<script>

import Card from "~/components/Card.vue";


export default {
  components: {
    Card

  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      imageUrl: require("../assets/imgs/logo.png")
    };
  },

};
</script>

<style scoped>

}
</style>
```

Can you tell me what's wrong? If I create an about-us page reusing the card component, I would like to change imageUrl prop.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `imageUrl` prop in your `Card` component, but aren't using it on your `index` page. You should be able to do `<Card :image-url="imageUrl">` on your index page.

One thing that is wrong however, is how you define your prop in your component.

Change it to this:

```js
props: {
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}
```

```js
Vue.component('card', {
  el: '#card-template',
  props: {
    imageUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      imageUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/1920x720'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.13.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.13.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <card :image-url="imageUrl"></card>
</div>

<template id="card-template">
  <b-card img-alt="Card image" img-top>
    <b-card-img :src="imageUrl" alt="Image" bottom></b-card-img>
    <b-card-text>
      Some quick example text to build on the card and make up the bulk of the
      card's content.
    </b-card-text>
  </b-card>
</template>
```